# カレンダーの月表示で数字を二桁に揃えたい

Tags: javascript

下記のコードを実行すると、10月、11月、12月のセレクトボックスの表示が010月、011月、012月になってしまうのですが、0を無くす書き方を教えて頂きたいです。

---

**HTML**

```
<input name="textYear"> 年
  <select name="selectMonth"></select> 月
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="textYear"]').on('change keyup',function(){
        $('select[name="selectMonth"] option').remove();
        $('select[name="selectMonth"]').append($("<option></option>"));

        if($(this).val() != ""){
            for(i=4;i<=15;i++){
                let m = (i<13)?i:(i-12);
                m =('0' + m).slice(-length);
                let y = (i<13)?$(this).val():parseInt($(this).val())+1;

                let op =$("<option></option>",{
                    value:y+m,
                    html:y+"年"+m+"月"

                });
                $('select[name="selectMonth"]').append(op);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

最後にこのコードですが、４は４月から始まるから４で１５はなぜ１５という数字が出てきたのか教えて頂きたいです。あと、１３とー１２の意味も教えて頂きたいです。
for(i=4;i<=15;i++){
                let m = (i<13)?i:(i-12);

Comment: 質問が解決したら、回答横の緑のチェックマークを押すことで[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)することができます。必須ではありませんがよろしければお試しください :)　今までご投稿くださった質問も同様に回答を承認することができます。

Comment: すいません、さがしてたのですが、どこにあるかわからないです。。回答横に緑のチェックボックス探してみます。

Comment: すいません押す前は灰色でした。また、チェックボックスではなくてチェックマーク✔です :)

Comment: やっとわかりました。。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m=('00' + m).slice(-2);
```

とすれば、とりあえず表示されるようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！０がなくなりました！！

Comment: おそらく「length」に意図した値が入っていないかと思われます。また同様の処理を行われるときに確認されるといいかと思います。

Comment: 承知いたしました。
for(i=4;i<=15;i++){
let m = (i<13)?i:(i-12);　　こちらはどういう処理内容か教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 15/ 13/ -12　の処理内容がわからないです。

Comment: let m = (i<13)?i:(i-12); は条件演算子というものです。「条件?Trueの場合；falseの場合」といった処理が行われます。ループが4-15としていて、４月から表示したいというサンプルだと思います。12月の次が1月を表示したいので「i-12」としていて上限を15にしているということですね。

Comment: なるほど、１５が上限としているからマイナス１２なんですね！ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 2):

`padStart()` を使うと簡潔にできます。

```
m = m.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

また、4から15のループになっているのは、4月から翌年3月(12 + 3)までの月を生成したいからと思われます。`(i < 13) ? i : (i - 12)`は、13から15の値を1から3に直しています。

Answer (score 1):

slice利用しない

```
let m = (i<13)?'0'+i.toString():(i-12).toString();
//m =('0' + m).slice(-length);
```

または、slice利用時

```
let m = (i<13)?i:(i-12);
m =('0' + m).slice(-2);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！両方試しましたら０がなくなりました！！！